# [IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified message when attemting to connect via isql

Tags: mysql, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to connect [Rattle](http://rattle.togaware.com/) to MySQL database. Both Rattle and MySQL are on my laptop (ubuntu 14.04). Since Rattle connects to MySQL only by ODBC I followed the post [here](http://www.kaffeetalk.de/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-with-unixodbc-under-ubuntu-14-04/) to install ODBC. I did the following

1. Installed the ODBC drivers using the following command

   apt-get install libmyodbc unixodbc-bin
2. My ODBC Driver location is as follows

   root@sridhar-Aspire-5745:/home/sridhar# find / -name 'lib*odbc*.so'
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/liboplodbcS.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcdrvcfg2S.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbctxtS.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcdrvcfg1S.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcminiS.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcnnS.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/liboraodbcS.so
3. Created the ODBC installation file (`/etc/odbcinst.ini`) with the following contents

   [myodbc_mysql] 
   Description             = ODBC for MySQL 
   Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so 
   Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so 
   UsageCount              = 6
4. Determined the MySQL Socket path

   root@sridhar-Aspire-5745:/home/sridhar# mysqladmin -u root -p version 
   Enter password:  
   mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu on i686 
   Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

   Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
   owners.

   Server version      5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 
   Protocol version    10 
   Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket 
   UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
   Uptime:         4 hours 41 min 49 sec 
    
   Threads: 1  Questions: 229  Slow queries: 1  Opens: 1156  Flush tables:     1  Open tables: 400  Queries per second avg: 0.013
5. Created `/etc/odbc.ini` with the following contents

   [myodbc_mysql_rattle] 
   Description             = rattle 
   Driver          = myodbc_mysql                 # custom driver name 
   Server          = localhost                    # or external IP if needed 
   Port            = 3306                         # or custom port if needed 
   Socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  # socket, see above 
   Database                = # MySQL DB name or empty 
   Option          = 3 
   ReadOnly                = No
6. Installed the ODBC driver

   root@sridhar-Aspire-5745:/home/sridhar# odbcinst -i -d -f /etc/odbcinst.ini 
   odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 7.  
       Target directory is /etc
7. Installed the system DSN

   root@sridhar-Aspire-5745:/home/sridhar# odbcinst -i -s -l -f /etc/odbc.ini
8. checked if the system DSN was installed successfully

   root@sridhar-Aspire-5745:/home/sridhar# odbcinst -s -q
   [myodbc_mysql_rattle]
9. Tested if I can connect to the MySQL DB (the **** indicates the password!)

   isql -v myodbc_mysql_rattle root ****

only to get

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified <br>
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I have repeated this 7 times! I am still unable to understand why the DSN cannot be found by isql.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming system files default location for unixODBC was not /etc. 
You might want to define & export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini and ODBCSYSINI=/etc